# How to get list values in Gravity Forms?

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I'm using gravity forms in wordpress.

I've added a list that allows the user to add/remove additional rows of information per field.

Each row has 2 fields.

The problem is I don't know how can I get the information using `rgar()`

For single fields that are not list, we use something like this : `rgar($entry , '4')`

What should I do in a list situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out myself !

All you need to do is this :

example : `unserialize(rgar($entry , '5'))`

This will return arrays that you can use. Simple.